How to import a private repo into a project using pipenv
I have a common utils repo with a setup.py. I am trying to install this in a new repo using pipenv and am struggling to get it running.
I don't often play with setup.py so am definitely doing something dumb through not understanding so any help would be appreciated.
Common utils repo
Directory structure looks like:
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── utils
        ├── __init__.py
        └── utils.py.py

Setup file looks like
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

from setuptools import find_packages, setup

install_requires = (...)  # some dependencies here

setup(
    name="common_utils",
    version="0.0.1",
    include_package_data=True,
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages("src", include=["utils"]),
    install_requires=install_requires,
    process_dependency_links=True,
)

New app that needs to access utils
This app has a Pipfile which should reference that should reference the repo
...
[ packages ]
common_utils = { git = "git@github.com:me/utils-repo" }


When I run pipenv install I get the below error:
ipenv.patched.pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Invalid requirement: 'common_utils@ git+git@github.com:me/utils-repo.git' (from line 2 of ...)
Hint: It looks like a path. File 'common_utils@ git+git@github.com:me/utils-repo.git' does not exist.

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong here because I am going to need to set this up in a few places and I definitely don't understand how setup.py builds the utils library.

Does it make a difference if you specify editable? I.e. { editable = 'true', git = "git@github.com:me/utils-repo" }

You could try adding the repository as a submodule:
git submodule add --name <repo name> -b <branch name>

If you subsequently need to update the submodule the command is
git submodule update --remote --init

Docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules
